# no port in upstream "9000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

can I ask some help for this error , I run this command `docker run --rm -it -p 80:80  myapp/jelo:latest`

`nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "9000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:17`

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
#RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update \
   &&  apt-get install –y nginx

COPY index.php /var/www/myapp
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is my **default.conf**

```
server {
        listen  80;
         index index.php;
         server_name myapp.local;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
         root /var/www/myapp;

          location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
           }

         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_pass 9000;
                 include fastcgi_params;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
             }
     }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems like fqm is not listening yet when nginx starts port 9000 is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are running a service in Port 9000

It should be somewhere in dockerfile, like

```
php start index.php --port 9000 --background
```

I'm not familiar with php

Comment: Is this command included when I create the conatiner `php start index.php --port 9000 --background` ?

Comment: You can also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247598/3854890