# Trying to run nginx image with php-fpm

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm just learning Docker and have a problem with running nginx together with php. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install php7.4-fpm -y
ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

start.sh content:

```
#!/bin/bash
service php7.4-fpm start
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

If I omit the last line `CMD ["/start.sh"]`, accessing files from the host machine works but php files aren't processed because php7.4-fpm is not running. But when I add this line nginx stops serving any files. Through I can confirm that nginx and php are running inside the container with `docker exec nginx-custom service nginx status` and `docker exec nginx-custom service php7.4-fpm status`. The nginx error log is empty.

This is the CMD of the original nginx image, which I thought is the only thing that gets overwritten? I guess I have some basic problems in understanding how Docker works at this point.

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: You'd almost always run these in two separate containers.  For a couple of reasons, commands like `service` don't work well in Docker.

Comment: You should really avoid running multiple main processes in a single docker container, it is against the Docker philosophy. So ideally would be you ran two different containers, one for Nginx and one for PHP-fpm and then link them together through network.

But if you really insist on using one, you should start from a Debian/Alpiune and install both Nginx and php-fpm and then run supervisord. Another possibility is to use apache which does not need another process to use PHP functionality.

Comment: I even found a good and very similar issue to yours on SO reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332919/combining-php-fpm-with-nginx-in-one-dockerfile)